# How to paint rows in NSOutlineView like in Finder.app

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview, finder

How can I set blue background for every second row in NSOutlineView, like it does Finder.app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSOutlineView`is a subclass of `NSTableView`and thus inherits the method `setUsesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors:`

If you send a YES to it, you get alternating background colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass NSOutlineView and do some drawing in

```
- (void)drawRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex clipRect:(NSRect)clipRect
```

Also have a look at other drawing methods available in TableView.  You can also make use of the delegate method i.e

```
- (void) outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)view willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)tableColumn item:(id)item
```